# Storage.get AWS => How to return url in react component?

Tags: es6-promise, aws-amplify

I want to return the url of my file stored in aws but I'm not good at will with promises...

```
Storage.get('sounds/feel the rythm_2.mp3', {level: 'private'})
.then(result => console.log(result))
```

But here it just return the url in the console, and I would like to return it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just return value from the Promise

```
Storage.get('sounds/feel the rythm_2.mp3', { level: 'private' })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);

    return result; // return value from promise
  });
```